# How to select employees who do not have a shift at the same time as a new shift time?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to make a select statement which gets the Firstname, Lastname and ID from an Employees table who do not have a shift at the same time as a given shift time.

There are two tables being queried. Employee table and Shifts table. 
Employee table has Firstname, Lastname and employeeID being retrived.
Shift table has CurrentOwnerEmployeeID(identfiyes with employeeID), startTime, and endTime. The startTime represents the start of a shift, and endTime represents the end of a shift.

I am trying to produce a list of employees who do not have a shift during the same time as a new shift. (new shift is a set of start and end Time).

Currently I have produced this select statement which is does not return a correct list of employees.

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, employeeID FROM `Employees` 
WHERE employeeID NOT IN 
(SELECT CurrentOwnerEmployeeID FROM Shifts 
 WHERE `date` = '2017-08-08' AND  `startTime` Between ".ShiftStart." and ".ShiftEnd.");
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data, what you get now, and what you want to get.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, consider storing dates and times as single entities.

Comment: What is your actual vs expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the query below.
Feel free to drop me a comment if it is still not showing.

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, employeeID FROM `Employees` 
WHERE employeeID NOT IN 
(SELECT CurrentOwnerEmployeeID FROM Shifts 
WHERE `date` = '2017-08-08' AND NOT ((`endTime` <= ".ShiftStart.") OR 
`startTime` >= ".ShiftEnd."));
```

In the query above, if the employee's shift does not fall between ShiftStart and ShiftEnd, there is only two posibilities, employee shift that not meet the scenarios below will be clashing with the new shift time:

1. endTime is earlier than shiftStart
2. startTime is after shiftEnd

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Edited, added some explanation to ensure that I understands the question correctly.

Comment: Did something strange happen during my lunchbreak? Time's still linear, right?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not so sure what you mean, could you elaborate further?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry I answered it the other way round, will fix it now

Comment: An event is never going to end before it starts, so if an end occurs before a given time then its start must do so as well.

Comment: @Strawberry you are right. Just me being stupid, fixed it.

Comment: Well, the OP appears to have fallen off the planet, so your labours may well be in vain

Answer (score -1):

Can I suggest using <> to code "not equal to"

```
SELECT Firstname
     , Lastname
     , employeeID 
  FROM `Employees`
 WHERE employeeID <>
       (SELECT CurrentOwnerEmployeeID 
          FROM Shifts
        WHERE `date` = '2017-08-08' 
           AND  `startTime` Between ".ShiftStart." and ".ShiftEnd.");
```